# Difference in the use of .hivelog and .out

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive

I got shellscript that runs a series of hive queries in it.
the result/log of every query to directed to a .hivelog file. But some places .out file is using. Can anyone explain me the reason/purpose of using .hivelog and .out files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.log` and `.out` files actually do the same thing, but with a slight difference. `.out` files are only written to when the process is starting. After process has started successfully, the `.out` files are truncated. By contrasts, all log messages can be found in the `.log` files, including the process start-up messages that are sent to the `.out` files.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is how you or your program interprets the filename. The operating system doesn't care. Does your program handle ".hivelog" files any differently from ".out" files?